# Android - Optimising multiple if-statements

Tags: java, android, optimization, if-statement

In my application, I have many IF statements that could be optimizing, but for the life of me can't work out a good possible solution without errors.

My current code:

```
    if (User_XP > -1){User_level.setText("1");Minimum_Level= Level1; Maximum_level = Level2;}
    if (User_XP > Level1){User_level.setText("1");Minimum_Level= Level1; Maximum_level = Level2;}
    if (User_XP > Level2){User_level.setText("2");Minimum_Level = Level2; Maximum_level = Level3;}
    if (User_XP > Level3){User_level.setText("3");Minimum_Level = Level3; Maximum_level = Level4;}
    if (User_XP > Level4){User_level.setText("4");Minimum_Level = Level4; Maximum_level = Level5;}
    if (User_XP > Level5){User_level.setText("5");Minimum_Level = Level5; Maximum_level = Level6;}
    if (User_XP > Level6){User_level.setText("6");Minimum_Level = Level6; Maximum_level = Level6;}
    if (User_XP > Level7){User_level.setText("7");Minimum_Level = Level7; Maximum_level = Level6;}
    if (User_XP > Level8){User_level.setText("8");Minimum_Level = Level8; Maximum_level = Level6;}
    if (User_XP > Level9){User_level.setText("9");Minimum_Level = Level9; Maximum_level = Level6;}
```

The idea of it is to work out a users level from a game, and from that create a percentage. But this area of coding is really not efficient as it can create multiple errors, anyone got any tips on a possible solution? 
Please ask if more information is needed.

Comment: I would recommend to use switch statements.

Comment: switch statements test for equality. If you want to test for a number being in a range then a switch won't help you.

Comment: What do you want to optimise _for_? Readability or speed?

Comment: Yes that true. I didnt saw it in the first place. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps store your level experience requirements in an array and use a loop.

```
int[] levels = new int[] { -1, Level1, Level2, Level3 };

int level;
for (level = 0; level < levels.length && userXp < levels[level]; level++) { }
int minLevel = levels[level];
int maxLevel = levels[level + 1];
userLevelText.setText(Integer.toString(minLevel));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something more generic?...

```
if (User_XP > Minimum_Level) {
    User_level.setText(Integer.toString(++Minimum_Level));
}
```

Of course if need the min/max instead of just doing a calculation..

```
if (User_XP > Minimum_Level) {
    User_level.setText(Integer.toString(++Minimum_Level));
    Maximum_Level = Minimum_Level + 1;
}
```

Then you could add in bounds checking before hand if you want to limit the absolute number if levels like `if(Minimum_Level == 10) return; //Too much awesome!`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 
User_level.setText(String.valueOf(User_XP-1);Minimum_Level = User_level; Maximum_level = User_XP;

or something in that lines will do the job. The point is there seems to be some logic there, you should be able to eliminate the if statement all together.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I prefer making a static [not the java key word] propertiesfile/map/table and store the details in the properties,map or table. And then at run time read from the map and set the appropriate values or do things. This help is expansion without coding by simply adding values to