# Android - For loop not incrementing integer

Tags: android, loops, for-loop, integer

I have a for loop which allows me to work out a level of a player, however the level doesn't get incremented after each loop, heres my code:

```
int[] Level_XP = new int[] {0,Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, Level5, Level6, Level7, Level8, Level9, Level10, 
          Level11, Level12, Level13,Level14, Level15, Level16, Level17, Level18, Level19, Level20, 
          Level21, Level22, Level23, Level24,   Level25, Level26, Level27, Level28, Level29, Level30,
          Level31, Level32, Level33, Level34, Level35, Level36, Level37,    Level38, Level39,Level40, 
          Level41, Level42, Level43, Level44, Level45, Level46, Level47, Level48, Level49, Level50};

int level;
for (level = 1; User_XP < Level_XP[level];level++) { }
Minimum_Percentage = Level_XP[level];
Maximum_Percentage = Level_XP[level+1];
User_Level.setText(Integer.toString(level));
```

I have intialised all the integers and there is an array being used, can anyone help me to actually increase the level after each loop? As this way the level only stays at level 1.

Comment: this should work, can you show the rest of the loop?

Comment: We need to know your array Level_XP

Comment: can you please post more of the code? especially the for loop?

Comment: For the confused (like myself), he's referring to an answer to his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315129/android-optimising-multiple-if-statements/5315252#5315252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for-loop is empty. That's why nothing happens there.

```
for (level = 1; User_XP < Level_XP[level];level++) { }
```

You didn't write anything in the curly braces. So your loop will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for that point out, however I have tried increasing it there but it doesn't increase the level on the for loop.

Comment: No-one mentioned increasing anything. Read the answer again.

Comment: Sorry, you was right, I was over looking it, I have it working now thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int level ;
for (level = 1; User_XP < Level_XP[level];level++) { }
Minimum_Percentage = Level_XP[level];
Maximum_Percentage = Level_XP[level+1];
User_Level.setText(Integer.toString(level));
```

There are quite a few problems with the above statements, even some code goes in the `for` loop.

1. What if `User_XP < Level_XP[level];` is always true ? You pass the array length and an exception is generated.
2. If condition satisfied for the very last element of the `Level_XP` in `for` loop, then

   `Maximum_Percentage = Level_XP[level+1]; // This causes exception`